# Limit the fields return by twitter api Json format

Tags: json, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have read the documentation provided by the twitter, but it seem I haven't found how to limit the fields returned in my script.

here's my script

```
  $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
  $params['count'] = 1;
  $params['oauth_version'] = '1.0';
  $params['oauth_nonce'] = mt_rand();
  $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
  $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $consumer_key;
  $params['oauth_token'] = $access_token;
```

what params should I add?

Answer (score 2):

There are few, if any, field (de)selectors for the Twitter API. Some timeline and tweet delivery methods support trim_user=true as a parameter to remove the fully embedded user objects but that's pretty much the only way to obtain less data per individual tweet object.